# как убрать стрелки в input в Vuetify

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuetify

Когда я пишу внутри v-text-field type="number" появляются стрелки, не знаю как их убрать. Обычный css не помогает

Style

```
     /* Chrome, Safari, Edge, Opera */
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

/* Firefox */
input[type="number"] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}
```

Сам v-text-field

```
<v-text-field
          label="Введите ваш ID код"
          ref="idCard"
          type="number"
          v-model="idCard"
          @input="$v.idCard.$touch()"
          @blur="$v.idCard.$touch()"
          :rules="[
            () => !!idCard || 'Это поле обязательно к заполнению',
            () =>
              (!!idCard && idCard.length <= 6) ||
              'Ваш id код не должен быть больше 6 символов',
          ]"
          counter="6"
          required
        ></v-text-field>
```

Comment: Попробуйте вместо  `type="number"` использовать `inputmode`. Тут подробнее
 https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/inputmode

Comment: При использовании просто уходят стрелки, но type number перестает работать.

Comment: а что Вам нужно от type="number", что не делает `inputmode="numeric"`?

Comment: Чтобы были только цифры, никакого текста

Comment: А при numeric текст можно писать

Answer (score 0):

Пропиши просто в App.vue

```
/* Chrome, Safari, Edge, Opera */
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}
```